# TypeScript module not found in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I tried adding typescript in my create-react-app project by renaming the .js files into .tsx and by installing it throught the CL like this:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react
npm install --save typescript @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

but when i restart the dev server i get the error "Compiled with problems: X ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\React\project\src' "

this is index.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Might be missing npm install --save @types/react-dom. Do check as well if App.tsx is saved correctly.

Comment: @Han no sorry that was just a typo in the question, i fixed it

Comment: Guess it's still due to App.js -> App.tsx. See the answer for sanka, most probably initializing tsc will work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these two steps?

1 - add TypeScript to the Project

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

2 - add the tsconfig.json

```
npx tsc --init
```

If it doesn't work, then you might need to delete your `node_module` folder and `package-lock.json` file, then install the dependencies again with

```
npm install
```

EDIT

If it is still not working, please refer to this [article](https://mxhdiqaim.hashnode.dev/adding-typescript-to-existing-reactjs-application). Thanks, @R Claven for mentioning here this article

Comment: I upvoted you for the effort but let's pls make sure that is compadible with every one that is using create-react-app.  This blog says they are https://mxhdiqaim.hashnode.dev/adding-typescript-to-existing-reactjs-application